# list-packages crashes Emacs 25.3 (Mac) when MELPA is added to .emacs

Tags: package-repositories

`M-x list-packages` crashes Emacs after I added:

```
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
```

after (package-initialize).

```
(package-initialize)
```

alone works fine but `M-x list-packages` lists only GNU ELPA packages.

Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure you're speaking of a crash? Does Emacs exit abnormally? If yes, this is an Emacs bug and should be reported with `M-x report-emacs-bug` and a crash log attached.

Comment: I tried every code I found and of course the one from the MELPA.org page:

Comment: @wasamasa: Yes, it is a crash. After I restart Emacs I get the message that Emacs crashed. I will try to contact the programmer of the Mac version.

Comment: Can you reproduce it (save your stuff before trying), starting from `emacs -Q` (then evaluating the above code)?

Comment: @Drew: I am not running the terminal version of Emacs but this standalone one: https://emacsformacosx.com/

Comment: You should still be able to run Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file).

Comment: @Drew: I deleted all my configuration files and added only what MELPA.org puts as configuration on their site to my .emacs file. Result: Emacs crashes.

Comment: This sounds like [Bug#30288](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=30288)

Comment: Changing melpa url from https to http may solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for posting another answer to my initial question. After [npostavs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/5296/npostavs) pointed to a known bug of Emacs 25.3 under macOS I installed the universal binary of Emacs 25.1 from https://emacsformacosx.com and indeed this version works just fine. Final verdict: It’s a Emacs 25.3 bug under Darwin / macOS.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue on OS X.

Comment: Sounds like you can accept this answer to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

It’s more or less official. This seems to be an issue with the Universal Binary of GNU Emacs 25.3 from https://emacsformacosx.com/ and not a general Emacs problem or my incompetence.
I shared my (crashing) configuration with the binary from http://aquamacs.org/ (Aquamacs 3.3 based on Emacs 25.1). With Aquamacs it works just fine.